# Correct way to remove key from react state

Tags: reactjs, state

I am using the state of a react (v0.14) view to hold key value pairs of unsaved user ids and user objects.  For example:

```
onChange = (user, field) => {
  return (event) => {
    let newUser = _.clone(this.state[user.uuid] || user);
    _.assign(newUser, {[field]: event.target.value});
    this.setState({
      [user.uuid]: newUser
    });
  }
}

render() {
   let usersJsx = users.map((user, i) => {
     return <div key={i}>
       <input type="text" value={user.name}
         onChange={this.onChange(user, 'name')}/>
     </div>;
   });

   let numberUnsavedUsers = _.keys(this.state).length;

   // ... etc
}
```

This all works perfectly until I come to the save method:

```
persistUsers = (event) => {

  let unsavedUsers = _.toArray(this.state);
  updateUsers(unsavedUsers, {
    onSuccessCb: (savedUsers) => {

      // Would prefer to remove these two lines and replace
      // with `this.setState({});` but this doesn't work... i.e.
      // the state is left untouched rather than being
      // replaced with `{}`.  This makes sense.  I guess I was hoping
      // someone might point me towards a this.replaceState()
      // alternative.
      this.setState({nothing: true}); // triggers a state change event.
      this.state = {};  // wipes out the state.
    }    
  });
}
```

I've searched around but only found people modifying nested objects or arrays and not top level key values.

Comment: Yeah @zerkms I think the only way around this would be to put all the unsaved users in an object in the state, such as:  `this.state = {unsavedUsers:{}};`  That way calling `this.setState({unsavedUsers:{}})` should then work.

Comment: you won't be able to call `this.state = {something}` in the future, it will throw.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<del>You need to use `replaceState` instead of `setState`</del>

**Update:** [replaceState is being deprecated](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/3236). You should follow the recommendation and use `setState` with null values.

**Recommendation:**

You should *name* the data and use `setState` so you can more easily work with it.

instead of:

```
//bad
this.setState({
  [user.uuid]: newUser
});
```

use:

```
//good
this.setState({
 newUser: {uuid: user.uuid}
})
```

If your state was `{unsavedUsers: {userData}}` instead of `{userData}` then you could easily `setState({unsavedUsers: {}})` without introducing `replaceState`.

replaceState is an anti-pattern because it is uncommonly used.

**Original Answer:**

> Like `setState()` but deletes any pre-existing state keys that are not in the newState object.

[Documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html#replacestate)

`this.replaceState({})` will remove all the objects.

Comment: "You should name the data in your state so you can more easily work with it" --- this is also an anti-pattern. Since its purpose is to work around the tool "limitations", instead of designing as per the domain model.

Comment: Yeah should have said that I'm using ES6 classes in TypeScript so replaceState is not available to me.  Also the deprecation notice on it put me off.  Thanks for confirming my hunch re using state object.

Comment: @zerkms The component state is not an existing domain model; it is not an anti-pattern to shape your state clearly around the state that's there. That's how state is supposed to work. Merging a domain model directly onto your state seems like an anti-pattern to me.

Comment: It looks like replaceState has been deprecated: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/3236. It doesn't appear in the react docs as of version 15.4.